# Flask server as a Class in Python

Tags: python, class, flask

I would like to use a flask server in my project. The project is extremely large so I would like to get have the flask server in a diffrent .py file. I want to have the server in a Class that should look a bit like this:

```
class SERV:
    def __init__(self, dbpath):
        self.dbpath = dbpath

    def __enter__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # do stuff at terminisation
        self

    def run(self):
        @self.app.route("/")
        def home():
            return render_template("index.html")

        def user_output(process, message, color, code, flashmsg, flashtype, redir):
            # def to communicate with user
            flask_ip = "127.0.0.1"
            time = datetime.today()
            print(
                flask_ip
                + " - - ["
                + time.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
                + " "
                + time.today().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                + "] "
                + '"'
                + colored(process + " " + message + '"', color)
                + " "
                + code
                + "-"
            )
            flash(flashmsg, flashtype)
            return redirect(url_for(redir))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = "tpsecret..."
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and then I would need to call:

```
from custom_modules.server import SERV

SERV("/db/server.db").run()
```

This to run my server in the main .py file.

Is this even possible to get a flask app in a class? The goal is to have a nice and tidy main file where I only call the serv class to start the server and may do some modifications and special events on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think you have to put the server into a class and that probably a separat file with a `start()` or `run()` function would do, but yes of course you should be able to put the code into a class.

What I think though is that you misunderstood what the functions `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` are used for.

Please run following example:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("exit")

    def run(self):
        print("running")


print("as instance")
C("123").run()


print("with a with statement ")
with C("234") as c:
    c.run()
```

And look at the output, which should look like:

```
as instance
running
with a with statement 
enter
running
exit
```

`__enter__()` and `__exit__()` are used for context managers.

If you want to use the code as indicated in your question move the code from `__enter__()` to `__init__()` and the code from `__exit__()` to a function named for example `__close__()` you might move it to `__del__()` instead

Comment: Yes, I was aware of the usage of __enter__ and __exit__. But what should I do with the last part: if __name__ == "main"? Also I agree with you that it could also be done with a simple function

Comment: Argh. Your comment changed while I answered.

OK. the `if __name__ == "__main__"`  is no more needed. You just run your app `app.run()` at the end of your `SERV.run()` function. 

I'd calculate the `appsecret` just before.

Comment: Ok, just did it and It works as a function. Thanks alot!